# ASP.NET Web API - Request Specific Global Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

When I receive a Web API request, I want to create a variable that will be accessible by every class during the life-cycle of the request. I want it to be accessed like a static property in such a way as `App.User` from any class. But I do not want it to be preserved after the processing of the request, so I guess SessionState is not an option. What would be the proper way to do this?

EDIT:
It needs to be thread-safe,too.

Comment: Add it to request properties

Comment: 1. Create a type that will serve as the container. 2. Use DI (dependency injection) to register a new instance per request. 3. Inject the type into your consuming types (controllers, services, etc). 4. Populate the type in the call stack as you see fit. DO NOT use static keyword for anything when it comes to web based code, you will do nothing more than shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: [HttpRequest.Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `HttpRequest.Items.Add()` @PeterB

Comment: @Igor Could you provide a simple sample snippet for your suggested solution please?

Comment: Adding a snippet will only lead to more questions than answers. If you want to use DI, and I highly recommend you do, then do a proper search for DI frameworks (I prefer AutoFac) and find some sample code on how to configure it. Once its configured it is very straight forward to extend with additional types you want to inject. If you want a previous answer I wrote see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35826744/1260204, heading `Solution 2 - IoC / DI` which has some sample code on configuring AutoFac.

Comment: @Igor "DO NOT use static keyword for anything when it comes to web based code, you will do nothing more than shoot yourself in the foot" Really? what about initializing some constant values that will not change, but you want it to come from database once (and not web.Config). Sounds like something i could use the static keyword.

Answer (score 3):

As [Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1260204/igor) notes, one option is to use dependency injection plus parameter passing to make your "global" variable accessible to everything that needs it.

But if you really want to use a static property, then you can use the [HttpContext.Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(v=vs.110).aspx) property to stash temporary data pertaining to just the current request:

```
public class App
{
    public static IUser User
    {
        get { return (IUser)HttpContext.Current.Items["User"]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Items["User"] = value; }
    }
}
```

A third option (which I *don't* recommend) is to use a static field backed by the [ThreadStatic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute:

```
public class App
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static IUser user;

    public static IUser User
    {
        get { return user; }
        set { user = value; }
    }
}
```

This option has the advantage that it has no dependencies on System.Web. However, it is **only** valid if your controller is synchronous, and it will break if you ever use `async`.

Comment: Is it thread-safe?

Comment: @JohnL.: Yes, HttpContext.Current.Items is thread safe, but in a narrow sense: Different ASP.NET requests have different Items collections, so different requests can freely access Items simultaneously. But note that HttpContext.Current is only available on "main" threads processing requests. Background threads can't access HttpContext.Current.

Comment: So, I can pass the necessary variable as a parameter to the thread, right? Would it be garbage collected after the request returns response? Because the background thread might continue after the response.

Comment: Yes, you can (and should) pass the variable to background threads. Objects won't get garbage collected until there are zero references to them, including from background threads.

Comment: Don't use ThreadStatic!  [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944979/does-a-single-web-request-to-iis-stay-on-a-single-thread)

Comment: @JohnWu: ThreadStatic can be safely used **if** (and that's a big **if**) the entire processing happens synchronously within the scope of a controller action (or more generally, within the scope of an IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest call). However, as I noted, I don't recommend its use.

Comment: If it all takes place within an action method or within a ProcessRequest method, seems to me a better solution would be a local variable.

Comment: @JohnWu: Yes, but the OP wanted a static property accessible from multiple classes.

Comment: Exactly.  He also wanted it to work throughout the entire processing lifecycle.  So I think we are in agreement.

Answer (score 2):

[HttpContext.Items](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/146455/when-can-we-use-httpcontext-current-items-to-store) is intended specifically for this purpose.

Anything you put in there will exist for the lifespan of the current request, then be demolished afterward.