# Web API - Accessing HttpContext inside DbContext class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In my C# Web API application I've added `CreatedDate` and `CreatedBy` columns in all of the tables. Now I want to populate these columns whenever a new record is added in any of the tables.

For this purpose I've overridden `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync` functions in the DbContext class like below:

```
public class AuthDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        AddTimestamps();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        AddTimestamps();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private void AddTimestamps()
    {        
        var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => (x.State == EntityState.Added));

        var currentUsername = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity?.Name)
            ? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
            : "SYSTEM";

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            foreach (var propName in entity.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
            {
                if (propName == "CreatedBy" && entity.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entity.CurrentValues[propName] = currentUsername;
                }
                else if (propName == "CreatedDate" && entity.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entity.CurrentValues[propName] = DateTime.Now;
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I call `SaveChanges` or `SaveChangesAsync` from anywhere in my controllers, `HttpContext.Current` is assigned and I can get the User name from it by using `ttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`. But when I use `UserManager.UpdateAsync` function (which internally calls `SaveChangesAsync` function in our DbContext class) to make changes to underlying user table, `HttpContext.Current` is set to null.

How can I access HttpContext in this particular case to fetch the User name?

Comment: How do you call UpdateAsync? Can you show it?

Comment: As a side note, I _strongly_ recommend you define an interface, say `IAuditable`, that declares the properties in question instead of messing around with strings. Also using `DateTime.Now` is almost certainly going to bite you.

Comment: How is your `AuthDbContext` is created? are you using DI container?

Comment: @AluanHaddad by your comment on using datetime.now, do you mean that he should use DateTime.UtcNow instead?

Comment: @Mart10 yes use `DateTime.UtcNow` if that is sufficient (i.e. you don't need to display them in local time ever) otherwise you'll need to use `DateTimeOffset` and also persist a time zone.

Comment: Getting the date time should be abstracted out as well to allow easier testing without time related side effects

Comment: @AluanHaddad Totally agree with you. Thanks for the the guidance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that with `SaveChangesAsync` you do not know if you will have access to the `HttpContext.Current` because you might not be executing on the thread that the request is being served on.

The best way to solve this problem is with DI. You can create an interface and matching class where the implementation relies on `HttpContextBase`. Configure the DI framework to inject an `IUserContext` instance into your `DbContext` and to create a new instance of `UserContext` per request.

As far as which DI framework to use I am partial to [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) but there are plenty out there to choose from and mostly have similar functionality.

```
public interface IUserContext {
   bool IsAuthenticated {get;}
   // additional properties like user id / name / etc
}

public class UserContext : IUserContext
{
  public UserContext(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
    this.IsAuthenticated = httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    // any other properties that you want to use later
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks Igor. It's similar to what you have already suggested in the comments of another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267255/asp-net-web-api-request-specific-global-variable

Comment: doesnt asp.net web-api support DI out of the box? or is it just aspnetcore?

Comment: @Mart10 - core is the one that has a built in DI framework. Asp.net (web-api/mvc) do not have a built in framework but it is easy enough to add a 3rd party di framework.