# Create/dispose user scope on same thread, per request

Tags: web-services, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack with ASP.NET web forms and Forms Authentication. I need the following logic per service call:

```cs
//-- on 'Begin Request' --
var identity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
if (!identity.IsAuthenticated)
    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
var user = //lookup user in Db using identity.Name
new UserScope(user) //store this somewhere(?) 

//-- on 'End Request' --
var scope = //get user scope
scope.Dispose();
```

Where should this logic go? The *Begin Request* portion seems like it could be handled by a request filter, but I'm not convinced that's the best place. Where should `UserScope` be stored and disposed? It must be created and disposed on the same thread.

#### UPDATE

I subclassed `ServiceRunner<TRequest>` and overrode `OnBeforeExecute`/`OnAfterExecute`.

```cs
public override void OnBeforeExecute(IRequestContext requestContext, TRequest request) {
    if (!IsLoginRequest()) {
        var identity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
        if (identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            var user = User.GetByUserName(identity.Name);
            if (user != null) {
                requestContext.SetItem(USER_SCOPE_KEY, new UserScope(user));
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
    }
}

public override object OnAfterExecute(IRequestContext requestContext, object response) {
    if (!IsLoginRequest()) {
        var userScope = (UserScope)requestContext.GetItem(USER_SCOPE_KEY);
        if (userScope != null)
            userScope.Dispose();
    }
    return response;
}
```

and overrode `AppHost.CreateServiceRunner`:

```cs
public override IServiceRunner<TRequest> CreateServiceRunner<TRequest>(ActionContext actionContext) {
    return new MyServiceRunner<TRequest>(this, actionContext);
}
```

Looking at the [source for `ServiceRunner`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/ServiceHost/ServiceRunner.cs#L93-144), it seems like `OnBeforeExecute`/`OnAfterExecute` should run on the same thread. Any reason this won't work?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using ServiceSTack's **IHttpRequest.Items dictionary**. This dictionary is available pretty much anywhere the request is available including the Request and Response filters. You can store your scope and retrieve it when needed.

As for the same threading issue you can't guarantee that the entire request will happen in the same thread. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1644015/215502 If you worried about threading with your asp.net I would be tempted to think you might be over-engineering something but hard to say without knowing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the question with my current solution. Do you see any issues with it?

Comment: Seems like it, but I wasn't sure about the potential threading issues, if there are any.